# Need execution time for a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure with out sys_refcursor return type. My requirement is to get the start and end time of execution of this stored procedure. how can I do that ?
The starttime should capture when procedure was called.
The endtime sould capture when procedure returned the response.

PS:- my requirement is not to print it on console as :-
dbms_output.put_line ('start procedure: ' || to_char(systimestamp, 'HH24:MI:SS.FF6'));

thanks

Comment: create a logging procedure  as `pragma autonomous_transaction` that inserts the start and end time into a table. Then you may query that table

Comment: Having time capture is to debug performance issue, by doing this I will introduce another performance overhead.

Comment: I'm with @Kaushik. If you have performance issues (obviously, you do - otherwise you wouldn't bother), "overhead" you're talking about is the least of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MSSQL then you can track with MS SQL Profiler with procedure name filter. and for mysql, you can enable the log from configuration.
Always procedure execution time doesn't help to us for better performance. Need to focus on commit/rollback or connection close time as well.